# Questions about UML Use Case Diagrams

Tags: model, uml, diagram, use-case

I am creating use case diagrams for various scenarios in my sample application I am creating. This is for pure learning and is not actually being implemented beyond the UML diagram planning phase.

The broad idea of this mobile application is a fitness program. A user would input what he does in the gym, can see his results of his activity, etc.. Only one user at a time, think a iPhone application.

So am I correct in assuming for something like this the only actor that would be involved would be the application user itself? Everything else would be handled by the system.

So for the purpose of my question I wanna just list out 5 hypothetical scenarios that the application user could encounter when he uses this application.

```
 1. User creates an account in the application
 2. User creates his own custom exercise he can perform
 3. User checks his fitness stats/activity/data (whatever you wanna call it)
 4. User exercises! (Records new data into the application)
```

So my question is, would this all be compiled into 1 single UML use case diagram? So would it look like A or B?

[image: Use Case Choices]

So for an application like this would all the possible uses by the application user be encapsulated into one single use case diagram (A)? Or should this be split up into multiple use case diagrams for each scenario (B)? Or am I missing the big picture all together? Is the use case diagram suppose to hide the implementation details or should I be elaborating further? I am not using any << extend >> or << includes >> relationships here because I'm not sure if I should be going into deeper implementation details.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

A is definitelly better.

Always group **related** Use Cases (or other elements) on one diagram to help the reader understand the context.

This **context** can be a lot of things, like:
- a functional modul
- use cases of a single actor
- use cases accessible from the same page
- all use cases (if the problem is small, like yours).
- whatever you find useful

Having single UC on a diagram has only disadvantages:
- more diagrams to draw (less productivity/efficiency)
- relationship between the use cases is lost (less clarity)
- model is larger and harder to search, navigate, maintain

Also keep in mind that UC is a set of scenarios and not a single scenario!

Answer (score 1):

Choice A is preferred as it gives the reader a broader overview of the use cases at a single glance.  This becomes more important as you have more actors:Application User, Tech Support, System Administrator, etc.  Some use cases are used by more than one actor and that is made clear by having multiple actors and multiple use cases on a single diagram.

Comment: Now would A be the Use Case diagram for the entire system, and then seperate use case diagrams for each individual case that dives deeper into the implementation details? Thanks for the response

Comment: There isn't much value to be gained from nested use case diagrams. They should be used to show the extent of the system and context of behavior, so they should be at a high level. Deep dives into use cases often end up in activity diagrams and sequence diagrams that capture specific scenarios.